# c make files, how to make one that will compile four source files?

Tags: c, windows, makefile

This is my homework. I'm looking for help on how to a make a "makefile" that will compile three source files. Of which will be named "timestable.c tablein.c tableout.c timestable.h". Those are the four source files. I have created a makefile to do this, which I believe is correct, but I'm not sure how to test it to see if it will compile? Here is the content of my makefile:

```
timestable.exe: timestable.c tablein.c tableout.c timestable.h
    cl timestable.c tablein.c tableout.c timestable.h
```

Is this correct? This makefile has to build a program called timestable.exe using the Visual Studio *cl* command and to provide the *clean* functionality. I don't understand what I am being told when the teacher mentioned the "*clean*" functionality. I'm not sure if this makefile actually works to create this file, because I'm not sure how to run it.

Also, if you guys don't mind giving me a link or telling me some more info on makefile commands for a windows based system. I wish to create and "extra feature" in my makefile because doing so will grant me better marks, and I do not know what more I could do.

Thanks ahead of time.

BIG EDIT: 
So, after playing around a bit, I figured out that if I change the makefile.txt file to makefile.bat and I open my visual studio cmd prompt, get into the correct directory and type in (I'm aware I do not have to run the cmd promt in order to run the .bat file) :

```
 makefile.bat
```

it will attempt to compile all the files. The issue, is it does not work with the ".h" file, specifitcly the timestable.h file. Also, the "timestable.exe" command didn't work. Any idea on what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Incidentally, what happens if you run `cl timestable.c tablein.c tableout.c timestable.h` by hand?)

You'd normally want to write your `Makefile` to compile your `.c` files to `.obj` files using  [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage) that know how to compile a single `.c` file into an `.obj` file and then another rule that knows how to link all the `.obj` files into a single executable object. (One important benefit is that this allows rebuilding only the parts that have changed. Your `Makefile` so far will require recompiling all inputs file any time any one changes.)

When you have so many `.obj` files laying around, you might want a `make clean` that removes all the object files and executable files that can be rebuilt from sources. That might be as simple as declaring `clean` to be a phony target and then deleting all the files that can be rebuilt.

Note that Makefiles are by convention named `Makefile` or `makefile` or `GNUmakefile`. (GNU `make` actually searches for the files in the *reverse order* to this list, but `Makefile` is the only name I like.) If you use one of these names, then you can just run `make foo` to run the `foo` target. If you pick a different name for your Makefile then you also need to use the `-f filename` command line option to pick the other file, and *that* is annoying. Sometimes necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for all the information, but I am a little bit confused. How can I run this make file to see if it works? Through the command prompt? Also, that clean you were talking about got me lost. Right now my makefile is a "makefile.txt" file sitting in the same spot as my other four source files. Do I change makefile.txt to something else? sorry.

Comment: The only real difference with the fundamentals described your answer is that object files conventionally have the `obj` extension, rather than `o`.

Comment: Considering that note, my makefile should just be "makefile" not "makefile.txt" ? And to run it I just open the visual studio cmd prompt and get into the same directory as this makefile, and run the makefile to create timestable.exe?

Comment: Yes, `makefile` is an acceptable name. You could use `cmd.exe`, or Cygwin's `bash`, or probably the visual studio command prompt -- though I don't know how that is implemented.

Comment: So how do I run makefile in the command prompt? just "makefile timestable.exe" ?

Comment: Yes. You can also run a bare `make` to run the first target in the makefile, which is supremely convenient. :)

Comment: "makefile  is not recognized ... " is the error I get in the command promt when running it.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake, I read too quickly. Just `make timestable.exe` -- assuming you've built the file correctly. :)

Comment: @Robsta, since you mentioned VS, it's actually `nmake`, not `make`.

Comment: @blindy: have I been going on and on about the wrong tool this whole time??

Comment: Not really, the format and stuff is the same, the tool is just called `nmake`.

Answer (score 0):

Surely your teacher/school provided some course notes, where the basics of `make`/`nmake` are explained, if they expect you to use it for your homework; or at the very least some pointers to online material?
You seem to be confused about what exactly a makefile is, and how you use it. You don't directly run it from the commandline like a batch script, but you need a program (called `make`, or `nmake` if you're using Visual Studio); the makefile is a sort of input script which is read by that program. The program then uses the info in the makefile to determine what commands it needs to run to update the main target.

You should be able to find some tutorials that describe the basics of `make` much better than I can do here. A quick search on Google for `make tutorial` came up with this link: http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/Make/ .
I glanced through it and it seems like a nice introduction (it uses pictures and short sections, so it must be good, right? ;) ).